# Approach to Android images in DB

Tags: android, sqlite, android-asynctask, picasso

It's an APP with kind of gallery context. Using **REST** I am receiving (Volley) JSON which contains information about place and few links to the pictures. Because there is about 60 places, so the caching form **PICASSO** is not enough. Data is stored in DB so I my idea was to insert an image to the database as `byte stream`. It's done, but in not so good way, presented below. Code inside `AsyncTask`.

```
@Override
protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {
    try {
        return Picasso.with(context)
                .load(site.getImageURL())
                .get();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
    super.onPostExecute(bitmap);

    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    site.setImageBytes(stream.toByteArray());

    db.openForWrite();
    db.updateSite(site.getId(), site);
    db.close();
}
```

My question is how to make it efficient, do you know better way to do that? I tried to `callback` to Picasso to add image to the DB `onSuccess`, but it require the view as a first argument.

Maybe there is a good ways of saving images to SD card, and replacing HTTP link with location of image on SD card.

Or caching image to the disc directly?

Comment: Use the cache, If you have the more number of images then you have to use the Disk Cache

Comment: i would suggest to download and store image on SDCard and store that path in db and check if they exists if not download else use the one present on SDCard

Answer (score 3):

There are several issues to note here:

1. `onPostExecute` runs on main thread. Not a good place to do disk IO. UI will freeze from time to time when images are being displayed.
2. SqLite blobs are faster than plain disk files only for limited sizes ([Benchmark](https://www.sqlite.org/intern-v-extern-blob.html)). So, large files are better stored on disk.
3. Using Picasso is advised if you want cached lazy loading on images. Problem is that Picasso won't allow to easily use your custom "DB as a cache" solution. It uses a general purpose HTTP cache. Hence, cached files may be periodically be invalidated and cleaned out.

If you want completely customizable HTTP and image loading, try something like Volley.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to go with caching, consider using [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) library by Sergey Tarasevich (GitHub)

it allows detailed cache management for downloaded images, with many configurations

> - UsingFreqLimitedMemoryCache -> The least frequently used bitmap is deleted when the cache size limit is exceeded.
> - LRULimitedMemoryCache: -> The least recently used bitmap is deleted when the cache size limit is exceeded.
> - FIFOLimitedMemoryCache: -> The FIFO rule is used for deletion when the cache size limit is exceeded.
> - LargestLimitedMemoryCache: -> The largest bitmap is deleted when the cache size limit is exceeded.
> - LimitedAgeMemoryCache: > The Cached object is deleted when its age exceeds defined value.
> - WeakMemoryCache: -> A memory cache with only weak references to bitmaps.

Answer (score 1):

To cache the images in android there are certain mechanism.

1. LruCache
2. DiskCache
3. Store in DB

If the images are not big & not more (2-3 KB) and the collection of them is not supposed to be expanded then you can save them to db. **But it would be harder to write them, read them**. On the other hand the user won't be able to do anything with them.

Otherwise, if you want to let user to expand the image collection or the images are rather big you should store them to **sd card (Disk cache)**.

> **Note :- I will recommend to use the Glide library with Disk cache mechanism**

[Glide](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en)

> Consider the space lackness and treat those cases appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Glide is really nice!

Comment: @Serafins Please go through this tutorial for more information http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en

Answer (score 0):

> Maybe there is a good ways of saving images to SD card, and replacing
>   HTTP link with location of image on SD card.
>
> Or caching image to the disc directly?

That's exactly what I would do. Look at the cache on SD if the image is present, if yes, use it, if not download it to the cache and use it from the cache. But you'll need to take care of the TTL-s.

Answer (score 0):

@Biju Parvathy answer is ok, but since Nov 27 the Universal Image Loader had stop the project maintaining. You can see it in their [github page](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

I think a really good alternative is using [Fresco Library](https://github.com/facebook/fresco). Is from Facebook and supports [local storage cache](http://frescolib.org/docs/caching.html) and a lot of other things. Some of the cache properties are:

> Bitmap cache
>
> Encoded memory cache
>
> Disk cache
>
> Using one disk cache or two

Its very easy to use and the time of downloading images is very quickly. Also it supports the streaming of [progressive JPEG images over the network](http://frescolib.org/docs/progressive-jpegs.html#_).

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, the "bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);" method accepts an output stream to save the bitmap.

Simply use a FileOutputStream and choose a location to save the image!

Answer (score 0):

Try [fresco](http://frescolib.org/). It's miraculous library from facebook!